# How to install XAPK packages on Android 4.4 (API 19)?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, apk

There is an Android 4.4 (KitKat, API version 19) device, that should get some external programs with XAPK packages. These XAPK packages does **not** contain any OBB files, they just have a "main" `.apk`, then a lot of configuration APKs.

How to install that mentioned XAPK files? If I install the APKs manually, then the app simply fails to launch. The `XAPK Installer` app, which could handle this, is available from Android 5+, so also not an option.

Updating or upgrading that device is also **not** an option. So, no need the comments like "that is outdated" etc.

Comment: Hi, please try the solutions on [How to install xapk, apks, or multiple-apks via adb?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/221204/44325) and let us know if it helps. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks @AndrewT., can You please let me know, how to use the adb on Linux?

Answer (score 0):

An XAPK package is basically ZIP files containing the different split APK files. Before trying to make an app work on your device I strongly recommend to you to extract the base APK files from the XAPK package and check the `minSdkVersion` in it's `AndroidManifest.xml`. You can do so easily by opening the main APK file e.g. in [Jadx](https://github.com/skylot/jadx) or any other tool that can decode and display the AndroidManifest.xml.
If this entry is 19 or lower there may be a chance to install the app on your device.

If I remember correctly the possibility to install multiple APK files as one app was introduced with Android 5, therefore the XAPK installer is limited to Android 5+. Also installing multiple APK files as one app via adb will not work. The only option I can see is building an universal APK from those multiple APK files inside the XAPK package. See section **Re-Building an universal APK** from my answer [Creating universal APK form multiple APKs without having *.aab](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/231306/2241):

> On the Internet you can find a tool named "SAP (Split APKs Packer)"
> which seems to allow to combine multiple split APK files into one
> universal APK file (if you have all the necessary split APK files)
>
> This "SAP" tool is available for Linux and Windows, however it is
> closed source and contains a lot of binaries. I am not sure if it is
> really trustworthy - I would not recommend to execute it outside of a
> protected environment (e.g. a virtual machine).
>
> The following [blog post](https://www.andnixsh.com/2020/06/sap-split-apks-packer-by-kirlif-windows.html) describes the SAP tool and provides download
> links.